# How could I Separate characters and numbers from an input and store as separate variables php

Tags: php

How could I Separate characters and numbers from an input and store as separate variables php for example my input string is as `$str="abc567"` and i need to separate it as `$str1="abc"` and `$str2="567"`.

Comment: Most answers so far are assuming that your input string always looks like CCC...NNN..., is that correct? Or can the characters and numbers occur in any order? Could the string even contain special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well `preg_split` will help you.

**Official Document** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

**Example**

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', "abc567"));
echo "</pre>";
```

above will out put.

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => 567
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_split using [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
print_r(preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', "abc567"));
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => 567
)
```

I hope this helps :)
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

By using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), you can pass a regex string. This will return all the patterns that match a given regex string, and you can use that to store the various values into their respective variables.

Notice there is no code here; you should be trying to work these things out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$str="abc567";
preg_match_all('/(\d)|(\w)/', $str, $matches);
$numbers = implode($matches[1]);
$characters = implode($matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are wanting all numbers and all letters in separate variables you can use:

```
$your_var = "abc567";
$str_letters = preg_replace('/[a-z]/', "", $your_var);
$str_numbers = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', "", $your_var);
```

Beware that if $your_var = abc7567d64h num = 756764 letters = abcdh